# Storage workload differentiate

Tags: virtualization, storage, bandwidth

I am searching some info about storage implementations. 
Came across random workloads which would be the bets measure by IOPS and sequential where measurement unit would be bandwidth. 
I would like to know how to differentiate the workload if you are planning for storage solution for virtual environment for example. How I could know if my workloads will be using random or sequential r/w.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't. But you can assume, that video library will most probably generate sequential workload. At the same time if you have an SQL database you would see random workload. Therefore try to find out what applications will run in your environment and make your decision.

Usually random IO affects the storage system much more then sequential, so if your storage system can handle random IO well enough it will also deal with sequential too. So if you don't know what type of workload you will have, assume it will be random.